# Get PID of subshell when variable is used

Tags: bash

I'm basically trying to add a progress wheel to a script to display whilst a pull from the database is taking place.

I'm calling a generic database function which echos back a result which is then stored in the result variable. Is there anyway I can background that, get the PID and then use that PID in the spinner wait?

```
loading_wheel(){
local process_id="$1"

spin[0]="-"; spin[1]="\\"; spin[2]="|"; spin[3]="/"

echo -n "[ Working ] ${spin[0]}"
while kill -0 $process_id 2> /dev/null
do
    for i in "${spin[@]}"
    do
        echo -ne "\b$i"
        sleep 0.1
    done
    done
    echo ""
}

# This is the command I want to background and use whilst still populating the variable.
result=$(get_db_val "$conn" "select 'test' from dual;")

# An example that works but no variable or subshell.
sleep 10 & PID=$!

loading_wheel "$PID"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't background a subshell and capture its output into a varaible reliable with a construct such as `foo=$(some_value_of_bar_that_takes_a_while) &`; you'll need to work around this limitation.  For the sake of brevity:

```
loading_wheel() {
    # is defined here
}
scratch=$(mktemp); trap "rm -f $scratch" EXIT
get_db_val "$conn" "select 'test' from dual;" > $scratch &
loading_wheel $!
result="$( cat scratch )"
```